# combobox getting value of selected value, winforms

Tags: .net, winforms

I have combobox cmbBoxA which is populated like this

```
private void FillComboBox()
        {
            foreach (var a in Helpers.Helper.GetData())
            {
                cmbBoxA.Items.Add(a);
            }
        }
```

GetData has this code

```
public static List<VATMode> GetData()
        {
            List<VATMode> vatModes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(VATMode)).
                Cast<VATMode>().ToList();    
            return vatModes;
        }
```

Now I'm trying to fetch selected combobox item is with

```
int sel = Convert.ToInt16(cmbBoxA.SelectedValue);
```

but It's always 0?

update:
enum is

```
public enum VATMode { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Enum

```
public enum Status { Active = 0, Canceled = 3 };
```

Setting the drop down values from it

```
cbStatus.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status));
```

Getting the enum from the selected item

```
Status status; 

Enum.TryParse<Status>(cbStatus.SelectedValue.ToString(), out status);
```

I hope it will help you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`ComboBox.SelectedValue` is used when your `ComboBox` is databound and yours is not.

Change your code like this:

```
private void FillComboBox()
{
     cmbBoxA.DataSource = Helpers.Helper.GetData();
}
```

and to get value back:

```
VATMode value;
Enum.TryParse<VATMode>(cbStatus.SelectedValue.ToString(), out value);
```

and then you can cast it to `int`